# How can I add a space between words in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that returns a row from a database table. When it is displayed in a textbox, the words all run together. For example:  `Everyonepleasebecarefulwhenleavingthebuilding`. I would like to separate the words to read: `Every one please be careful when leaving the building`. This comes from user input, so the user clicks on whatever row he wishes to be displayed in the textbox. Each row contains different data. The code listed below is what triggers the event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table tr").click(function(){
        $("#txttread").val($(this).text());
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pickme tr').not(':first').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('highlight'); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass('highlight'); }
    ).click( function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected').find('input').attr('checked','checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: Or a more important question, how do you know where to add space?

Comment: It may be easier to fix it with the server side code that is retrieving the information from the DB.  In your jQuery, I don't see anything that would cause the words to run together.  If you show us more code, we might be able to see the problem :)

Comment: The data is in a table that can has 8 columns. Each word is in its own cell in the table and each row can be different, but they all have 8 cells in a rown. I have been able to extract whatever cell is clicked on and I get whatever is in that cell. When I ask for the whole row it comes all joined together like in that example above.

Comment: what is the sql query used to get the results? we may help you to add spaces there.

Comment: you need to paste in the HTML you're using, too. i assume the strings coming from the server have the proper whitespace, and something you're doing in jquery is causing the whitespace to be removed. but it's impossible to know without the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

When a table-row is clicked, cycle over its table-cells, adding each of their words to an array. Lastly, join that array by spaces and set its result as the value of your input field:

```
​$("#statements").on("click", "tr", function(){
    var words = [];
    $("td", this).text(function(i,v){ words.push( v ); });
    $("#txtread").val( words.join(" ") );
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EXPBp/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through each cell and get its text separately, instead of just grabbing the text of the row:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table tr").click(function(){
       $("#txttread").val($.map($(this).children('td'), function (item) { return $(item).text() }).join(' '));
  });
});
```

Working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/kSsYD/